# Force multiple websites with NGinx, Varnish and dedicated IP's from non-www to www

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, varnish

I'm dealing with this for days and need help fellows! I hope somebody here han solve this:

**3 Wordpress websites** (3 dedicated IP's)

I've used this Ansible playbook to deploy: https://github.com/zach-adams/hgv-deploy-full

This is the fullstack:

**Ubuntu 14.04 (Dedicated Server, no firewall)**

- Percona DB (MySQL)
- HHVM (Default PHP Parser)
- PHP-FPM (Backup PHP Parser)
- Nginx Varnish (Running by default)
- Memcached and APC
- Clean WordPress Install (Latest Version)
- WP-CLI

All working ok. I checked headers and Varnish is working. When I try to force 301 from non-www to www with Varnish in each individual site, it enter in a url redirect loop. I added to the Nginx configuration this line as i read in some documentation:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

It doesn't work and i think it's for the Varnish configuration. I followed some of this documentation but nothing worked for me:

- https://www.tinywp.in/varnish-301-redirection/
- https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/www-non-www-redirection/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

I hope somebody can illuminate me :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect from non-www to www using Varnish you will neeed to do the following:

1- Disable any redirect rules that written in nginx configuration.

2- redirect non-www to www through varnish using the following snippet:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "example.com") {
        set req.http.host = "www.example.com";
        error 750 "http://" + req.http.host + req.url;
    }
}

sub vcl_error {
    if (obj.status == 750) {
        set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
        set obj.status = 301;
        return(deliver);
    }
}
```

Note: I used the above snippet today and it worked correctly for me (it will work with Varnish 3 which is used in the playbook that mentioned in your question)

If you would like to redirect using nginx you can try this:

```
server {
    listen 8080; # modify this with your current nginx port
    server_name  example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 8080; # modify this with your current nginx port
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /path/to/example/files/;
    # ...the rest of your config file goes here...
}
```

Use one method only either varnish or nginx. In case you have nginx as the front end i suggest you to go with nginx way.